# "if" condition on "groupby" in list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a sequence in which I want to count runs (i.e. consecutive identical entries), and return a list of the length of the runs. The code below

```
from itertools import groupby

S = [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5]

grouped_S = [sum(1 for i in group) for key,group in groupby(S)]
```

Results, as it should, in

```
[3, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

But I want to ignore spells that are 1-long, and get output just [3,2,2]. This

```
grouped_S = [sum(1 for i in group) for key,group in groupby(L) if sum(1 for i in g) >1]
```

gives

```
[0,0,0].
```

It clearly knows I want just the three sequences > 1, but won't return their length.

I don't understand this behavior, could someone please explain? Right now my solution is:

```
S = [sum(1 for i in g) for k,g in groupby(S)]
S = [i for i in S if i != 1]
```

and it works, but there has to be a pythonic one-liner I can't figure out.

Comment: groupby is not a builtin function, please provide a minimal, reproducible example (by including the packages you are using)

Comment: I am guessing g is some type of iterator/generator that is exhausted. Thus when you do the sum the first time, it uses up all the values, then the sum of what is left is zero. I wonder if `len` would work.

Comment: thank you for the feedback, this is my first stack question, I'll edit question to include packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @deceze already pointed your variable `g` is an iterator:

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator):

> iterator
>
> An object representing a stream of data. Repeated calls to
>   the iterator’s **next**() method (or passing it to the built-in
>   function next()) return successive items in the stream. When no more
>   data are available a StopIteration exception is raised instead. At
>   this point, the iterator object is exhausted and any further calls to
>   its **next**() method just raise StopIteration again print([len(g) for
>   k, [*g] in groupby(S) if len(g) > 1])

you can make your `g` variable a list by using [iterable unpacking operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
print([len(g) for k, [*g] in groupby(S) if len(g) > 1])
```

**output:**

```
[3, 2, 2]
```

Comment: thanks @kederrac, I ended up following your advice on the g variable list, more readable that putting in a lambda function

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation of `groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) points out:

> The returned group is itself an iterator that shares the underlying iterable with `groupby()`.

You can only iterate an iterator once, which you're doing in the `if`; there's nothing left in the iterator to `sum` again then. It would be far easier to simply filter the `1`s out of the result:

```
grouped_S = list(filter(lambda s: s > 1, (sum(1 for i in g) for k,g in groupby(S))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could very well save your variable in a list comprehension and then check it afterwards:

```
from itertools import groupby

S = [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5]
grouped_S = [group
             for k,g in groupby(S)
             for group in [sum(1 for i in g)]
             if group > 1]

print(grouped_S)
```

This yields

```
[3, 2, 2]
```